# Maximum call stack size exceeded TypeScript Recursive Function returning a Generator returning a Promise

Tags: typescript, recursion, generator

I have a generator that streams one line of a large file at a time. I only want to process one line at a time and the file size is likely to get quite large.

```
export async function *lineOfFileGenerator(fullFilePath: string) {
  const filestream = createReadStream(fullFilePath);
  const rl = createInterface({
    input: filestream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  for await (const line of rl) {
    yield line;
  }
}
```

It is then instantiated

```
const gen = lineOfFileGenerator('./path/to/file')
```

I want to keep calling this generator (which returns a promise) until it is 'done'. Since it returns a promise, I can't loop and directly check if the done boolean is true. I made a recursive function

```
function genPrinter(geno: any): void | AsyncGeneratorFunction {
  geno.next().then((val: { done: boolean; value: string; }) => {
    if (val.done) {
      console.log('done');
      return;
    }
    // will eventually call a processing function.
    console.log(val.value);
  });
  return genPrinter(geno);
}
```

However, I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I'm not sure of the best way to call this generator/solve this problem.

Comment: You are always calling `genPrinter`  regardless of the result of your promise (because that promise that is retuned from the generator is still pending) The `return` inside the `then` handler does NOT  return from the `genPrinter` function but just from the `then`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm confused because if I don't add the `return genPrinter(geno)` the console logs the value of val, not "pending".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions expect some condition to exit. In your case you called `genPrinter` endlessly, in this case you don't need a recursive function, just an `await..for` loop to do the work. Here I refactored your code a bit:

```
async function genPrinter(geno: any) {
  for await (let val of geno) {
    console.log('value:', val);
  }
  console.log('done');
}
```

If you still want to do same thing, in your method try this:

```
async function genPrinter(geno: any): void | AsyncGeneratorFunction {
  let { done, value } = await geno.next();
  if (done) {
      console.log('done');
      return;
  }
  console.log(value);
  return genPrinter(geno);
}
```