# Testing Async Generator with Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Clearly, I have a massive misunderstanding about how this should work, especially in testing (with Jest). When I try to do an await... of loop I don't get anything out. The file path that I pass into the generator is correct and I have tested that the file exists in a previous test.

```
    expect(
      statSync('path/to/file.csv').isFile()
    ).toBe(true);
```

Here is my async generator that returns a promise of a line of a file. (I asked about this in another question [Maximum call stack size exceeded TypeScript Recursive Function returning a Generator returning a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69699858/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-typescript-recursive-function-returning-a-gener/69700886#69700886))

```
export async function *lineOfFileGenerator(fullFilePath: string) {
  const filestream = createReadStream(fullFilePath);
  const rl = createInterface({
    input: filestream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  for await (const line of rl) {
    yield line;
  }
}
```

How do I access the yeilded values in Jest please? For testing I am passing in a small file.

```
const gen = lineOfFileGenerator('path/to/file.csv');

for (await let retVal of gen) {
      console.log(retVal.value);
    }
```

Jest complains if I try to log `val.value`. It doesn't seem to get into the loop at all when I add this kind of thing to a test, it won't log even if I try a string like "hello". when I tested the function that calls this generator, I noticed it only gets called once.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [Iterating over async generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#iterating_over_async_generators), the iterative variable(`retVal`) is the value `yield` by asynchronous generator functions. It's not generator, so there is no `value` field.

E.g.

```js
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');

async function* lineOfFileGenerator(fullFilePath) {
  const filestream = createReadStream(fullFilePath);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: filestream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });
  for await (const line of rl) {
    yield line;
  }
}

(async function test() {
  const gen = lineOfFileGenerator(path.resolve(__dirname, './test.txt'));
  for await (let retVal of gen) {
    console.log(retVal);
  }
  // console.log(await gen.next());
  // console.log(await gen.next());
  // console.log(await gen.next());
  // console.log(await gen.next());
})();
```

`test.txt`:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Output:

```sh
⚡  node index.js
line 1
line 2
line 3
```